# CSS property overwritten by WebResource.AXD

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik

I'm working on a website developped with C#, ASP.Net and Telerik components. I have a RadButton that doesn't display properly an image I'm trying to set to it.

Tracing the styles with Firefox, I've seen that my image is shifted by some properties (padding) that come from a file called WebResource.axd.

I tried to play with the padding property of my button directly within the Default.CSS file but it keeps being overwritten by this WebResource.axd.

So far, I've found that the keyword `important` in order to force my properties to be used no matter which parameter is used later.

Within Default.CSS :

```
.rbLinkButton {
    padding: 0px 0px !important;
}
```

It works but, it feels bad and I feel like I'm introducing an evil shortcut here... Is there a better way of doing that ?

Comment: placing your style, after the webresource.axd will also overwrite it.

Comment: I dont know how to place my style after it... I'll give it a second look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is to increase the specificity of the CSS rule so that yours takes place. More info here: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/08-06-17/how-to-override-styles-in-a-radcontrol-for-asp-net-ajax-embedded-skin.aspx